# Insert 'DATE' values in to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

My table has a BIGINT column which holds time in milliseconds (EPCOH time). I want to add a new column in the same table with type as DATE.

I have about a million rows in the table. I now have to copy the BIGINT values, covert them to DATE value and INSERT the newly created column. Is there a easier way to do this?

I can do the following, but i need a way to do it all at once

```
INSERT INTO test (TIME_NORMAL) VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME(TIME_EPOCH/1000));
```

|

Comment: Do UPDATE instead, something like `UPDATE test SET TIME_NORMAL = FROM_UNIXTIME(TIME_EPOCH/1000)`.

Comment: Do you want to update a (new) DATE column in your existing same table based on the old representation (BIGINT) date information you have?

Comment: Do you want `DATE` or `DATETIME` values? If you want `DATE` values(which have a time of midnight) you'd be wise to use this expression: `DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(TIME_EPOCH/1000))` so it's clear you're throwing away the time part of your timestamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you want `update`:

```
update test
    set time_normal = FROM_UNIXTIME(TIME_EPOCH/1000);
```

If you don't have the column already, then add it using `alter table`:

```
alter table test add time_normal datetime;
```